# split an array into two based on condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this below.

```
[
    {
        product_id: 4,
        product_name: "Samsung",
        category_name: "Tv and home appliance",
        is_Available: 1
    },
    {
        product_id: 8,
        product_name: "Apple",
        category_name: "Home gadgets",
        is_Available: 1
    },
    {
        product_id: 9,
        product_name: "Verifone",
        category_name: "Electronics",
        is_Available: 0
    }
  ]
```

I want to split this array into two based on **is_Available** flag value. So i did like this using reduce.

```
const formmattedResponse = data.reduce((arr,el) => {
            if(el.is_Available === 1) {
                arr.push({...el});
            }
            return arr;
        },[]);
```

But, i need this type of formatted data like below based on above data array

```
{
    availableData: [{
        product_id: 4,
        product_name: "Samsung",
        category_name: "Tv and home appliance",
        is_Available: 1
    },
    {
        product_id: 8,
        product_name: "Apple",
        category_name: "Home gadgets",
        is_Available: 1
    }
   ],
  notAvailableData: [{
        product_id: 9,
        product_name: "Verifone",
        category_name: "Electronics",
        is_Available: 0
    }
   ]
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could take an array and push the objects according their availability with a single loop.

```js
const
    data = [{ product_id: 4, product_name: "Samsung", category_name: "Tv and home appliance", is_Available: 1 }, { product_id: 8, product_name: "Apple", category_name: "Home gadgets", is_Available: 1 }, { product_id: 9, product_name: "Verifone", category_name: "Electronics", is_Available: 0 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.is_Available ? 'availableData' : 'notAvailableData'].push(o);
        return r;
    }, { availableData: [], notAvailableData: [] });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

The lodash [`partition`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partition) function was designed to solve this problem:

```
import { partition } from "lodash";
const [availableData, notAvailableData] = partition(items, "is_Available");
const formattedResponse = { availableData, notAvailableData };
```

where items is the array of objects given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [
    {
        product_id: 4,
        product_name: "Samsung",
        category_name: "Tv and home appliance",
        is_Available: 1
    },
    {
        product_id: 8,
        product_name: "Apple",
        category_name: "Home gadgets",
        is_Available: 1
    },
    {
        product_id: 9,
        product_name: "Verifone",
        category_name: "Electronics",
        is_Available: 0
    }
  ];
const result = {
  availableData:  data.filter(el => el.is_Available),
  notAvailableData:  data.filter(el => !el.is_Available),
};

console.log(result);
```

You can use Array.filter() to filter your array based on is_Available.

Comment: It's better to only iterate once which can be achieved with a reduce

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: you either filter the list twice or you can add a different accumulator for your reduce function which holds two arrays.

This advantage of the reduce is that only iterate your array once, making it more efficient than the double filter.

I pass a object with 2 properties: availableData and notAvailableData as the initial value for the reduce.
During the reduce, I check the property that you want to filter on and add it to the right list.
In the reduce function, I return the context object so the next iteration has it also.

The reduce returns that object in the end, completing the sort.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    product_id: 4,
    product_name: "Samsung",
    category_name: "Tv and home appliance",
    is_Available: 1
  },
  {
    product_id: 8,
    product_name: "Apple",
    category_name: "Home gadgets",
    is_Available: 1
  },
  {
    product_id: 9,
    product_name: "Verifone",
    category_name: "Electronics",
    is_Available: 0
  }
]

var context = arr.reduce((ctx, el) => {
  if (el.is_Available) {
    ctx.availableData.push(el);
  } else {
    ctx.notAvailableData.push(el);
  }
  return ctx
}, {availableData: [], notAvailableData: []})

console.log(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reconsidering the decision to split your data. It might not be the best choice. Instead, it could prove very beneficial to perceive your data as divided. Creating a `TrueSet` and a `representation` function  enables you to perceive them as divided without losing the ability to iterate through all of them.

```
const 
    repr = item => [item.is_Available, item.category_name, item.product_name, item.product_id],
    set = new TrueSet(repr)
        .letAll(data),
                
    got = {
        availables: set.class(1).toArray(),
        unavailables: set.class(0).toArray(),
        electronics: set.class(undefined, 'Electronics').toArray()
    }
```

The `class(...keys)` method iterates through all items that share the specified `keys` in their representation. Therefore, the `class(1)` iterates only through the `available` items, while the `class(0)` iterates only through the `unavailable` ones. However, even though items might seem to belong to two distinct collections, they still belong to the same collection. For instance, all items categorized under 'Electronics' can be retrieved regardless of their availability using `class(undefined, 'Electronics')`.

You can check the validity of the proposed solution by:

```
import {TrueSet} from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import assert from "assert";

const data =  [
      {
        product_id: 8,
        product_name: "Apple",
        category_name: "Home gadgets",
        is_Available: 1
      },     
      
      {
        product_id: 4,
        product_name: "Samsung",
        category_name: "Tv and home appliance",
        is_Available: 1
      },

      {
        product_id: 9,
        product_name: "Verifone",
        category_name: "Electronics",
        is_Available: 0
      }
    ],

    expected = {
        availables: data.filter(item => item.is_Available),
        unavailables: data.filter(item => !item.is_Available),
        electronics: data.filter(item => item.category_name === 'Electronics')
    };

assert.deepEqual(got, expected)
```

Further delineation of this split perception is achievable using the `view(...keys)` method. Nevertheless, a comprehensive explanation would extend the content considerably. I suggest referencing the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library's online documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

modified Snippet could be like

```js
const formmattedResponse = data.reduce((arr,el) => {
          let finalResp = { 
                  availableData: [],
                notAvailableData : []
            }
            if(el.is_Available === 1) {
                finalResp["availableData"].push({...el});
            } else {
        finalResp["notAvailableData "].push({...el});
     }
            return finalResp;
        },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can find partition functions in some libraries e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partition) that will split an array into two arrays, one that matches the condition and another that doesn't. I've written a quick version here to demo it.

```js
const data = [{"product_id":4,"product_name":"Samsung","category_name":"Tv and home appliance","is_Available":1},{"product_id":8,"product_name":"Apple","category_name":"Home gadgets","is_Available":1},{"product_id":9,"product_name":"Verifone","category_name":"Electronics","is_Available":0}];

const partition = (array, filter_fn) =>
  array.reduce(
    (acc, val) => (acc[filter_fn(val) ? 0 : 1].push(val), acc),
    [[], []]
  );

const new_keys = ['availableData', 'notAvailableData'];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  partition(data, (item) => item.is_Available)
    .map((arr, i) => [new_keys[i], arr])
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If not using lodash, may I suggest this :

```js
var arr = [
  {
    product_id: 4,
    is_Available: 1
  },
  {
    product_id: 8,
    is_Available: 1
  },
  {
    product_id: 9,
    is_Available: 0
  }
]

const res = {notAvailableData: []}
res.availableData = arr.filter((a) => a.is_Available || !res.notAvailableData.push(a))

console.log(res)
```

`.push()` returns the new length of the array, so ![].push shouldn't ever be true