# I want a function to filter between pass and fail base on name and type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that removes element with duplicate names and now i wanted to add additional logic to remove invalid types. example:

`

```
const values = ["SS.csv", "Account.csv", "Location.png"]
const supported_names = ["SS", "Account", "Location"]
const SUPPORTED_EXTENSION = 'csv'


const partitionFiles = (values: any, supported_names: any) => {
  let pass: String[] = [];
  let fail: String[] = [];
  for (const supported_name of supported_names) {
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      const file = values[i];
      if (
        file.toLowerCase().includes(supported_name.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        pass.push(file)
        break
      }
    }
  }

  for (const value of values) {
    if (!pass.includes(value)) {
      fail.push(value)
    }
  }

  for(const name of values){
    if(!name.includes(SUPPORTED_EXTENSION)){
      fail.push(name)
    }
  }

  return [pass, fail]
}

const [validFiles, invalidFiles] = partitionFiles(values, supported_names);


console.log(validFiles)

console.log(invalidFiles)
```

`

Right now the code push the Location.png into the fail arraw, however, since the name match criteria is still in the pass array. I want to remove any element that does not match name and type... any help?

`

```
for(const name of values){
    if(!name.includes(SUPPORTED_EXTENSION)){
      fail.push(name)
    }
  }
```

`
this is the new line i added that adds value that doest match type to the fail array... how can i remove that element from the previous array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split an array into two based on condition using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67333594/split-an-array-into-two-based-on-condition-using-javascript)

Comment: also: [Dividing an array by filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731072/dividing-an-array-by-filter-function)

Answer (score 1):

I created this sample:

```
const values = ["SS.csv", "Account.csv", "Location.png"]
const supported_names = ["SS", "Account", "Location"]
const SUPPORTED_EXTENSION = 'csv'

function checkIfValid(item) {
    let sliptted = item.split(".")
    return supported_names.includes(sliptted[0]) && SUPPORTED_EXTENSION.includes(sliptted[1])
}

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    console.log(checkIfValid(values[i]))
}
```

returns:

```
true 
true 
false
```

In your code this could be for example be used like this:

```
for (const value of values) {
    let sliptted = value.split(".")
    if (!(supported_names.includes(sliptted[0]) && SUPPORTED_EXTENSION.includes(sliptted[1]))) {
        let index = pass.indexOf(value);
        pass.splice(index, 1);
        fail.push(value)
    }
}
```

I hope it helped.